# Django ListView with subquery gives This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

Tags: django

I have the following model:

```
class Credit(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(User)
  ...
```

and a ListView

```
class CreditListView(ListView):
  paginate_by = 10
  model = Credit
  ...
```

if I want to filter the credits by users in side CreditListView:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    users = User.objects.filter(...)[:10]
    credits = Credits.objects.filter(user__in=users)
    return credits
```

I will get a NotSupportedError exception:

```
(1235, "This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'")
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this :

```
users = User.objects.filter(...)[:10]
users = list(users)
credits = Credits.objects.filter(user__in=users)
```

Django model returns a list which exactly isn't a Python list but an extended form of that. But that has some limitations. Hence, we need to convert that into a Python understandable list.

Comment: When you do `users = User.objects.filter(...)[:10]`, no SQL operation is performed.

The moment you do `user = list(users)`, and SQL query is executed on the DB. Next time when you iterate over credits, another SQL query is executed on the DB.

That is why there is no longer a subquery. There are two different queries to the DB.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was this line:

```
users = User.objects.filter(...)[:10]
```

It doesn't like the limit within the subquery, I thought I have tried removing it, could be django server didn't restart properly.

Answer (score 0):

> (1235, "This version of MySQL doesn't yet support '**LIMIT &
>   IN**/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'")

Pagination is responsible for the LIMIT and your queryset for the IN. You might be able to get away by rewriting the query with include/exclude or by using index ranges instead of pagination. If not, use raw SQL to get your queryset.

In general using MySQL (with MyISAM in particular) is a very painful idea, because apart from its problems as a database, it does not support 20-25% of Django's ORM. If you can not switch to PostgeSQL, try using InnoDB.